# Ionic: different providers for different platforms

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I am building an application for web, iOS and Windows.
The web portal however needs to make calls to a REST API and the mobile applications need to store and retrieve the data from a local database. So I am going to need two different providers. How do I split up this code if i want only one Ionic project? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) for this, for example:

```
  constructor(public platform: Platform){}

  someRequestmethod() {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      //work with ios
    } else if (this.platform.is('windows')) {
      //work with windows
    }
  }
```